# Wamp, Route External IP to one file and Internal IP and Localhost to Wamp HomePage

Tags: networking, apache-http-server, ip, routing, wamp

So I recently downloaded WampServer and was wondering if there would be away for me to be able to route my external IP address and my internal IP address, along with Localhost, to separate locations. I want my external IP address to redirect to a specific file in my wamp/www directory while I want my internal IP and Localhost to redirect to the standard Wamp HomePage. 
I tried to configure my  httpd.conf file in the appache sever and changed

```
 DocumentRoot "C:/Server/wamp/www/" and <Directory "C:/Sever/wamp/www">
```

to

```
 DocumentRoot "C:/Server/wamp/www/test" and <Directory "C:/Sever/wamp/www/test">
```

However, this change now redirects all 3, the external IP address, the internal IP address and the Localhost to the place where I only want the external IP address to go to.

Thank you to anyone who helps. :)

Comment: You will need to create a `.htaccess` file that uses Apache's Rewrite engine to look at the `REMOTE_HOST` address (to match the IP you want to redirect) and redirect when the condition is met. Look up `htaccess redirect by IP`. OR http://serverfault.com/questions/558421/redirect-specific-ip-using-htaccess

Comment: You need to create Virtual Hosts for each of your sites, look at this post for help on how to setup Virtual Hosts http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23665064/project-links-do-not-work-on-wamp-server/23990618#23990618